# Accessing windows applications controls from Linux

Tags: linux, controls, window

I'm currently using Linux as my main OS and I run some Windows applications via Wine.  Let say I'm running Notepad under Wine for example purposes.  Is there a way I can access the text entered in notepad from Linux ? (Java, C, C++, C#/mono).

Language doesn't matter

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean to access the contents of the window as it's running, or to access some saved text file?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I meant to access the contents of the window as it's running.

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to accomplish with this. It's nearly guaranteed that there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is saved than you can share the file. If it is not saved I double you will find a solution. may be it can be coded but it will be very hard to do it!